# How to get values in both queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database and i'm trying to get the results in both queries how do i do it?

```
SELECT distinct cliente.nome_cliente,marcas.nome 
FROM cliente 
inner join cliente_marcas on cliente.id = cliente_marcas.id_cliente 
inner join marcas on marcas.id = cliente_marcas.id_marca 
WHERE `status` = '1' and id_marca = 3 
union
SELECT distinct cliente.nome_cliente,marcas.nome 
FROM cliente 
inner join cliente_marcas on cliente.id = cliente_marcas.id_cliente 
inner join marcas on marcas.id = cliente_marcas.id_marca 
WHERE `status` = '1' and id_marca = 4;
```

I've tried `where id_marca = 3 and id_marca = 4` but it doesnt work.
This is what i'm getting but i only want the names that are in both queries.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: No, it return the same.

Comment: OR, not AND. `id_marca = 3 AND id_marca = 4` will be always false. You can use `IN` instead, it'd be shorter.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, `id_marca ` can't be two values at the same time, do you mean `or`?

Comment: Sounds like you need `INNER JOIN` and not `union`.

Comment: Inner join is only for tables

Comment: I want to get the duplicate values that are in both queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join those two subqueries and match them by name. For example:

```
select
  a.*, b.*
from (
  -- query 1 here
) a
join (
  -- query 2 here
) b on a.nome_cliente = b.nome_cliente
```

If you need the full expanded query, it should take the form:

```
select
  a.*, b.*
from (
  SELECT distinct cliente.nome_cliente,marcas.nome 
  FROM cliente 
  inner join cliente_marcas on cliente.id = cliente_marcas.id_cliente 
  inner join marcas on marcas.id = cliente_marcas.id_marca 
  WHERE `status` = '1' and id_marca = 3 
) a
join (
  SELECT distinct cliente.nome_cliente,marcas.nome 
  FROM cliente 
  inner join cliente_marcas on cliente.id = cliente_marcas.id_cliente 
  inner join marcas on marcas.id = cliente_marcas.id_marca 
  WHERE `status` = '1' and id_marca = 4
) b on a.nome_cliente = b.nome_cliente
```

Comment: wow, yeah it works. Thanks